# save each text file's contents into a database table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file-get-contents, tokenize

I got 100 text file with a .txt extension. I want to save the contents of a text file from each file into a MySQL database table, in the field, where fieldnya name I gave the name "token". so the structure of my tables are: id, filename, token, size. I've tried with the following php code :

```
it is my code :
 <?php
  include_once 'connection.php';
  $array_file = glob('savetoken/*.txt');
  foreach ($array_file as $token_words) {
  $string_Text = file_get_contents($token_words);
  global $string_Teks;
  } 
if(isset($_POST['btnUpload']))
    {    
$FileInput = $_FILES['data_upload']['name'];
$file_loc = $_FILES['data_upload']['tmp_name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['data_upload']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['data_upload']['type'];

$folder="savestopword/";
$UploadDirectory = 'c:/xampp/htdocs/try/savestopword/';
$new_size = $file_size/1024;  
$new_file_name = strtolower($FileInput);
$final_file = str_replace('','_',$new_file_name);
global $final_file;
$File_Name          = strtolower($_FILES['data_upload']['name']);
$File_Ext           = substr($File_Name, strrpos($File_Name, '.')); 
$NewFileName        = $File_Name;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['data_upload']['tmp_name'], $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName ))
   {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO token_keyword(filename,token,size) VALUES('$final_file','$string_Text','$new_size')";
    mysql_query($sql);
   echo "<script>";
    ?>
    alert('successfully uploaded');
    window.location.href='upload_modifikasi.php?success';
    <?php
    echo "</script>";
    die('Success! File Uploaded.');
    include "upload_modification.php";
}else{
    die('error uploading File!');
}   
if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
{

}
else
{
    ?>
    <script>
    alert('error while uploading file');
    window.location.href='upload_modification.php?fail';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
   }
  ?>
```

For testing I use three text files. when I use the code, when I upload a text file that occur are:
file successfully uploaded to the database table, the file was successfully saved to the storage directory, and no error. but what happens on the field token is a text file of all the contents of the three documents into the field .txt token, when what I want is when uploading one file, field token only store the contents of the file, instead of storing the content of all files. nah how the solution? I've tried to googling but have not found a way.

Comment: Show us how you save the data. In the other hand, anyway in your `foreach()` you should test for files (i.e. not work for directories, including `.` and `..`).

Comment: I store the data in this way:
  $ Sql = "INSERT INTO token_words (filename, token, size) VALUES ('$ final_file', '$ string_Teks', '$ new_size.KB')";
mysql_query ($ sql);

Comment: And how do you populate `$final_file` and `$new_size`? Please show your real complete code in your question. BTW: currently `$string_Teks` actually gets only the _last_ processed file content.

Comment: $final_file from here : str_replace('','_',$new_file_name); 
$new_size from here : $file_size/1024;

Comment: Wow! Your code is a total mess! Too much points where it has absolutely _no sense_, such as: 1) `global` used while the variable has been already set; 2) `foreach()` resulting in only last file processed; 3) `glob()` working on _server's local files_ while the rest of code targets _client's uploaded files_; 4) `<script>` sequences generated but never used because `die` follows... and so on. First of all you should find somebody a bit experienced near you to explain how to logically organize your work.

Comment: the problem is success finished, i just add one line code like this : $string = file_get_contents($_FILES['data_upload']['tmp_name']); and work 100%

Comment: Sorry: I don't understand anything, at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
<?php
include_once 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['max_filesize']))
{
    $FileInput = $_FILES['FileInput']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['FileInput']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['FileInput']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['FileInput']['type'];
    $folder="yourdirectoryforsavefile/";
    $UploadDirectory = 'c:/xampp/htdocs/yourfolder/yourfolder/';
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    $new_file_name = strtolower($FileInput);
    $final_file = str_replace('','_',$new_file_name);
    $File_Name = strtolower($_FILES['FileInput']['name']);
    $File_Ext = substr($File_Name, strrpos($File_Name, '.')); 
    $NewFileName = $File_Name;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FileInput']['tmp_name'], $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName ))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO yourtablename (name,size,type)   VALUES('$final_file','$new_size','$file_type')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        echo "<script>";
        ?>
            alert('successfully uploaded');
            window.location.href='upload.php?success';
        <?php
        echo "</script>";
        die('Success! File Uploaded.');
        include "upload.php";
    }else{
        die('error uploading File!');
    }   
    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
            alert('error while uploading file');
            window.location.href='upload.php?fail';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```